# Randomizing Array visibility/appearance (hard to explain)

Tags: modeling, texturing, modifiers

So i got this reference video:

https://youtu.be/CDKUX0X34nY

[image]

the polygons seems to appear one by one
then all the polygons middle got filled with another thing

[image]

How do i recreate that ?

Here's what i've done:

I'm using noise texture as the factor of Transparent shader and the emission shader
but the problem is, the reveal is "gradual" not one by one polyon like in the reference
I would love to hear / see a better solution to this, maybe not using array in the first place ? who knows

[image]

Comment: we just see pictures...no videos :( But i am pretty sure this can be done with geometry nodes or Animation nodes or Sverchok ;)

Comment: I uploaded the reference video just now, maybe it will help to visualize it

Comment: Thank you…I will try ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is [Ducky 3D](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCuNhGhbemBkdflZ1FGJ0lUQ)'s trick that may be your solution:

Make one separate mesh for each hexagonal object, unwrap, in the *UV Editor* choose *Individual Origins* as *Pivot*:

[image]

Scale down the UV islands until you have small UVs like this:

[image]

Give your object a material with a mix of *Emission* and *Transparent*, and Separate XYZ as factor to get a gradient on the axis you want. Use the *Texture Coordiante* UV output and play with the *Mapping* values to make the wave move. Tweak the *ColorRamp* needles if you want more or less contrast:

[image]

Of course you can make the material more complicated and mix the *ColorRamp* with another one that has a *Noise* plugged etc.

Comment: amazing ! I'll give it a try, but the link to ducky3d you gave me led to his channel, not to the exact video
maybe i'll watch it if i need extra detail, but i think the answer you gave me will suffice for the moment

Comment: I don't remember which video it is but the trick is just to scale down the UVs with pivot set at individual  ;)

Comment: great....and a liiiiiiiiiiiiitle bit quicker than my solution ;)

Comment: a bit old school though  ;)

Comment: i am always learning from your solutions... ;) and of course you saved my life a few time when i was desperate.... ;)

Answer (score 3):

The node setup is very basic. I just use the grid to place my hexagons. The hexagons i created by creating a Mesh -> Circle -> and changing the vertices to 6.

[image]

Then go to edit mode, select all in vertex mode, G -> Z move a bit up.

The "filler" is the same, but instead of moving up, i just pressed F to fill the hexagon.

The grid was a bit trickier. I created a normal grid and selected every 2nd row and moved it a bit that it looks like this:

[image]

I am sure you can do this better, i did it manually because of my lack of knowledge :(

The geometry node setup just uses the frame to ask whether it's greater than a special frame, then it will "show" the filler / hexagon by just scaling it up from 0 -> 1. The time when this happens will determined randomizely (i am not sure whether this is written correct).

For the animation i rotated the grid a bit and used a bit compositing.

my compositing:

[image]

my geometry nodes tree:

[image]

my result loos like this:

[image]

https://youtu.be/_8opaiOD38I

blend file:
[image]

Comment: damn... i never touched geometry nodes.... i think i'll need to learn geometry nodes... this looks so cool, thanks chris !

Comment: You are welcome!!

Comment: And yes…you should. It is amazing!! But Animation nodes and Sverchok are also very very amazing!!